# How to enable drag and drop on GridView item's onClick()

Tags: android, gridview, android-animation

I want to drag the item in the `GridView` to the first position if it is not in the first position  on item's `onClick()`. The other items must rearrange as drag and drop of the `GridView` item.

I used  [Dynamicgrid](https://github.com/askerov/DynamicGrid) library for drag and drop and tried dragging an item to the first position on item `onClick()`. I am unable to find a solution.
Suggest if dragging onclick can be done with Dynamicgrid library or can use some other library?.